# Extract email from CNContactProperty - iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, contactpicker, cncontact

I have an iOS app which needs access to the Contacts picker view controller in order to allow the user to select a contact property such as email address/ telephone numbers of imessage email addresses.

The problem I am having right now, is that I can't figure out how to parse the returned data. I have made use of the `contactPicker didSelectContactProperty` method, but I am unable to parse the data I need.

```
-(void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContactProperty:(CNContactProperty *)contactProperty {

   CNLabeledValue *test = contactProperty.contact.emailAddresses.firstObject;
   NSLog(@"%@", test);

   NSLog(@"%@", contactProperty.contact.phoneNumbers);
}
```

If you run the above code you get the following response:

```
2015-10-11 13:30:07.059 Actions[516:212765] <CNLabeledValue: 0x13656d090: identifier=21F2B1B2-8158-466B-9224-E2036CA07D28, label=_$!<Other>!$_, value=News_Europe@iEUNS.com> 2015-10-11 13:30:07.061 App_Name[516:212765] (
    "<CNLabeledValue: 0x13672a500: identifier=6697A0E9-3B91-4566-B26E-83B87979F816, label=_$!<Main>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x13672a660: countryCode=gb, digits=08000391010>>" )
```

Thats great, but how do I extract the data I need from it? Why are the NSLog statements returning the data in a weird format?

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The returned values are of the [CNLabeledValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNLabeledValue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CNLabeledValue/value) class. In order to get the value from them, for, say, the emails, do this

```
CNLabeledValue *emailValue = contactProperty.contact.emailAddresses.firstObject;
NSString *emailString = emailValue.value;
```

If the value you wanted a phone number, this is how you would retrieve that

```
CNLabeledValue *phoneNumberValue = contactProperty.contact.phoneNumbers.firstObject;
CNPhoneNumber *phoneNumber = phoneNumberValue.value;
NSString *phoneNumberString = phoneNumber.stringValue;
```

Because the returned value is a `CNLabeledValue`, you are also able to retrieve the phone number's or email's label

```
NSString *emailLabel = emailValue.label; //This may be 'Work', 'Home', etc.
NSString *phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumberValue.label;
```

Comment: Ah right I see. Thanks so much. I have just upgraded from using the older AddressBook framework, so I was struggling with this. Thanks again :)

Comment: Just one question, I am expecting the user to select either an email address of a telephone number. How can I check what they have selected?

Comment: I think that that information would be stored in `contactProperty.value`, `contactProperty.label`, `contactProperty.key`, etc. I would test each of those and see what it outputs, as I've never used this before personally.

Comment: Awesome, ```contactProperty.key``` works perfectly. Thanks Chris :)

Comment: I promise this will be my last question, but do you know if there is some sort of ```indexPath.row``` number I can use? (Instead of ```emailAddresses.firstObject```). So I could do ```emailAddresses[indexPath.row]```.

Comment: If you mean that you need the index of the selected email address, I believe that `contactProperty.value` points to the email and that, as a result, you don't need to use the `emailAddresses` array.

Comment: Ah right I see. Brilliant, I promise I wont pester you anymore. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey @ChrisLoonam, when I try to get the label of `CNLabeledValue`I get a text like this :  "_$!<Home>!$_"

Comment: yes, i got this result, but i want to get only work email, not other email like home and etc.

Comment: To get properly localized labels instead of strings like "$!<Home>!$", use this code: [CNLabeledValue localizedStringForLabel:[phoneNumberValue label]];

Comment: Would this still work if you've got multiple addresses and the user has selected anything other than the first address?

Answer (score 2):

### Swift

This is the proper way how to do it:

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
    if contactProperty.key == CNContactEmailAddressesKey,
       let emailAddress = contactProperty.value as? String
    {
        print(emailAddress)
    }
}
```

If you would select `contactProperty.contact.emailAddresses.first`, you would get the first email address of the contact which might not necessary be the email address the user has selected.

In case you are querying phone numbers, use the following body instead:

```
if let phoneNumber = contactProperty.value as? CNPhoneNumber {
    print(phoneNumber.stringValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For swift 3.0 :

```
 public func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact)
{
      if let emailValue : CNLabeledValue = contact.emailAddresses.first
    {
        txtEmail.text = emailValue.value as String
    }
    if let phoneNumber : CNLabeledValue = contact.phoneNumbers.first
    {
        txtMobno.text = phoneNumber.value.stringValue
    }
     txtFname.text = contact.givenName + " " + contact.familyName

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Chris' answer tells you how to get the value from the CNLabeledValue object that is returned, but it doesn't tell you how to identify what CNLabeledValue was selected based on the contactProperty parameter the function features.

What you need to do is cycle through each of the contact's email addresses and check if it's identifier matches up with the selected contactProperty identifier. Use the following code inside the didSelectContactProperty function:

```
NSString *selectedEmail;

for (CNLabeledValue<NSString*>* email in contactProperty.contact.emailAddresses) {
    if ([email.identifier isEqualToString:contactProperty.identifier]) {
            selectedEmail = (NSString *)email.value;
    }
}
```

Note I have only tested this code with postal addresses, so it may require some further tweaking to work with email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is swift version of Chris answer :

 func fatchContacts(store : CNContactStore)  {
    do
    {
    let groups = try store.groups(matching: nil)
    let predicate =  CNContact.predicateForContactsInGroup(withIdentifier: groups[0].identifier)
    //let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("John")
        let keyToFatch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName ) ,CNContactEmailAddressesKey] as [Any]
    let contacts = try store.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keyToFatch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])            //------------------------------------------------------
   //-------------Get Here-----------------------------------------
     print(contacts)
     print(contacts[0])
        let formatter = CNContactFormatter ()
        print(formatter.string(from: contacts[0]))
        print(contacts[0].givenName)
        print(contacts[0].emailAddresses)
        let emailValue : CNLabeledValue = contacts[0].emailAddresses.first!;
        let  email = emailValue.value
        print(email)




    }
    catch{

    }
}


Just pass the CNContactStore object
```