# iOS Objective C: Get user selected phone number from CNContactProperty as a string

Tags: ios, cncontact

My question is basically the same as the question here:

[iOS Swift: Get user selected phone number from CNContactProperty as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631312/ios-swift-get-user-selected-phone-number-from-cncontactproperty-as-a-string?answertab=active#tab-top)

WHICH HAS BEEN WRONGLY MARKED AS DUPLICATE WITHOUT SOLUTIONS (Reason stated in that post).

I desperately want to know the answer, it should be very simple, because I can see Skype is using exactly the same API to retrieve contacts and I want to know how.

Swift or Objective C is not important only the idea matters, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

After a few hours trying I figured it out myself:

We first need to get the "identifier" property of CNContactProperty and then fetch the chosen number that matching it.

```
- (void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContactProperty:(CNContactProperty *)contactProperty {
    CNContact *contact = contactProperty.contact;
    NSString *identify = contactProperty.identifier;//pick the number according to this id!!!
    _lastDisplay = @"";
    for (CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber*>* number in contact.phoneNumbers) {
        if ([number.identifier isEqualToString:identify]) {
            _lastDisplay = ((CNPhoneNumber *)number.value).stringValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Leave it here if anyone needs it.

Answer (score -1):

### Swift

You can simply type cast `CNContactProperty` to `CNPhoneNumber`.

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
    if let phoneNumber = contactProperty.value as? CNPhoneNumber {
        print(phoneNumber.stringValue)
    }
}
```